# Find closest target in a network using GraphHopper

Tags: routing, graphhopper

A person is somewhere in a city and wants to know the network distance to the closest supermarket.

Is there any way I could solve this problem with the [GraphHopper program/library](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper) (not the API)?

Comment: Put in the coordinate of the person and the coordinate of the supermarket or iterate over the list of supermarkets and pick the closest?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Graphhoper One To Many shortest paths  using this code:

```
L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    origin point,
    points of interest
  ],
  router: L.Routing.graphHopper('your token'),
  parameters: {
    vehicle: 'car'
  },
  routeWhileDragging: false
}).addTo(map);
}
```

or just use [leaflet-knn](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn) to check points of interest within a specific distance (euclidean distance) and afterwards use Graphhopper compare those routes and choose to serve the shortest one.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Like stated in my question I do **not** want to use the API. I want to do it purely offline using the GraphHopper Java program.